# How can I adjust Cycles material displacement amount?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, node-editor

The experimental feature set in Blender 2.75 includes an option to allow the *displacement* socket of the *material output* node actually displace the mesh instead of acting as bump-mapping.

[image]

However I can not figure out how to control the actual displacement amount.  Simply adding a *math multiply* node does absolutely nothing.

[image]

So how can I change the actual displacement amount?

Comment: change the displacement to true.

Comment: @cegaton I already did.  It is displacing some in the viewport, I just can't adjust how much.

Comment: @cegaton I just fixed the screenshot.  I accidentally took the screenshot before I changed it.

Comment: I figured it out.  It seems that it doesn't refresh the displacement real-time in rendered view mode.  You have to exit rendered view mode and go back again to see the changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember this in an **experimental feature** it doesn't update atomatically every time. To force update **Exit Rendered View** to solid view and switch back to Rendered view. Or Render with <kbd>F12</kbd> and you'll see the difference.

With True Displacement x10
[image]

With True Displacement x20
[image]

Comment: This is a great feature, but how do you change the "midlevel"? My mesh looks puffy because it's going too far outward.

Comment: Can you share an image? To cotrol the displacement you might need to alter the contrast of the image that's driving it. Use a gamma or a RGBcurve node. Keep in mind that his way of displacing geometry is not as controllable as the displacement modifier.