# Crumpled Paper Cycles Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm trying create a crumpled paper material in Blender Internal. It's pretty easy, here's my result just using Voronoi texture with little setting:

[image]

But when I've moved to Cycles, it is not getting close in material nodes using Voronoi, Noise & Musgrave textures.

Just give me little step to make this crumpled paper in Cycles, I'll do the rest...

What I needed exactly:

[image]

Comment: Please add more information on what you've tried, are you trying to do this with material nodes or with a displace modifier?

Comment: i'm trying using material nodes add voronoi, noise textures, and musgrave but it's more like rock

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work/50442#50442 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34902/how-can-i-adjust-cycles-material-displacement-amount/34903#34903

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1**

In my opinion you'll bet better control using a displacement modifier instead of using the displacement on the material nodes.

The controls for the voronoi texture are much more detailed for textures.

Add a plane, subdivide it a lot (I did 100 subdivisions on this example)
then add a displace modifier and use a voronoi texture to control the displacement. Play with the feature weights, scale, intensity,brightness and contrast as well as with the strength of the displacement for the modifier.

[image]

For more nuanced textures you can use different displacement maps with different settings. Note that the quality of the displacement is related with the amount of vertices on your mesh. For a nice looking paper you might need a lot of vertices. In this case I added a subsurf modifier before the displacement to further subdivide the mesh.

**Option 2**

If what you are after is to create a bump map (with no real geometry displacement just plug in a voronoi texture to the displacement socket of the material output.

[image]

Note that this will give you just the illusion of relief.

Note also how very little control you have on the voronoi texture.

You can combine more than one texture to create the larger and smaller folds.

**Otpion 3**

To create real displacement you need to enable the **experimental** features on the render settings.

Then set the displacement control on the material settings to **true** displacement.

Then the textures connected to the displacement socket will affect the geometry of the object.

[image]

For a detailed and more random looking displacement combine several textures.

[image]

Note that you will not see the displacement in wireframe, solid or texture shading, only on material or rendered shading. Also render shading will not update when making changes, only material shading will update in real time.

Comment: great i try to use options 3. hope  get best result realistic tiny crumpled paper

Comment: i try in hour but still not getting close, i hope you give me advice what kind any other texture / vector node should i use. thanks a lot

Comment: DId you not see anything i posted???

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite sorry i didn't want use any image texture. I need generated by blender only

Comment: Then why did you post that texture?

Comment: thats for references only

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is being upvoted when it clearly looks nothing like paper.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, subdivide your mesh into four even squares. Use the loop cut for this. Then subdivide the mesh 2 or 3 times (not with subsurf modifier).

Use the texture as a bump map for the tiny details.
[image: Node Setup]

Follow the order of modifiers and settings.
This will make big wavy displacement,then subdivide for more polys and then triangulate.
[image: Modifier Setup]

Make sure the displacement also uses the texture.
[image: Displacement texture]

Comment: This is the main concept. You'll have to search the methods of displacement and bump maps in detail to get perfect results.

Comment: Why are your SubSurf and your Triangulate Modifiers below your Displacement? They have no purpose that way. Also, I'm sure you can find a better texture than one with watermarks.

Comment: Please conduct the experiment before making these conclusions that mislead other readers. The displacement needs to be on top so that it can create the waves of the paper. If the displacement goes below the subfurf, it will displace the subsurf mesh as well, creating a mess.The triangulate can go below or above subsurf depending on art direction.

Comment: And I used the texture posted above for clarity.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I am confused with the Displacement Modifier being above the SubSurf, since a texture with the detail you are using won't really do anything to a mesh with only four faces.  I am confused with your Triangulate Modifier being below your SubSurf Modifier, since there is nothing further being done to the mesh. The triangles the modifier creates won't be seen; they'll just be in co-planar pairs and look like quads.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm sorry. I failed to add that after I made four faces, i subdivided the mesh 2 or 3 times. I will make the edit.

Comment: What about the Triangulate Modifier?

Comment: To make smaller triangles. If it goes above subsurf, the triangles will be coarse.

Comment: The mesh is already triangulated before render...

Comment: You have to do it to understand what I mean. I'm moving the modifiers as we speak and they do create different effects.

Comment: I have done it. I'm not denying that it creates a different effect, it just seems redundant.