# How to make paper page material?

Tags: materials

What is the best way to create real looking paper page? [image: Like this]

I can make sides easy with textures, but can get result with that page base.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/crumpled-paper-cycles-texture

Comment: Will you be animating the page?

Comment: No, not animating. Just trying to create interior scene with some open books and other papers, like students table on the last night of deadline :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your question, the first thing that popped into mind is the need for *Subsurface Scattering*, so light is able to pass through the pages.

First of all, make the "Diffuse" shader a slightly yellow color, and then connect the shader output to an "Add Shader." Create a "Subsurface Scattering" shader and connect it to the other input slot o the "Add Shader" node. Try to pick a slightly yellow, slightly grey color for the "Subsurface Scattering" shader. Thyis will let yellowish light from other light sources seep through the pages, making it appear translucent. Make sure to crank up the samples when you do this, because this shader can cause a lot of fireflies.

For added realism, you can connect a simple "Noise Texture" node directly to the displacement, which will give the page a nice texture. In the end material set-up should look something like this: [image]

Finally, here's the material in all its glory: [image]

Just about every organic or living object has this property, so I hope I helped you out. Let me know if you have any questions. Happy Blendering! Cheers,
**Graves Broderick**

Comment: I changed "Noise texture" scale to ~1000 so paper looks a little rough

Comment: Sounds good! Yeah, I didn't know how textured you wanted the paper. Good luck!