# Displacement Node Artefacts

Tags: displacement

For the text I'm using a greyscale-texture that I plug into the displacement output. Everything is correct using low values. But if I increase the value of the multiply-node in order to receive more depth some black lines start to appear.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to fix that? Or is there an other way to achieve more depth?

Comment: Does the displace map have a soft edge? Perhaps you could sharpen it before use? I guess that means that the map should be normalised 0-1

Comment: The displacement socket will make the texture plugged into it work as a bump map, multiplying the values just increases the contrast on the shadowing, making it less realistic. To make the extrusion real, you need to enable the **experimental** feature set and set the displacement to "*true**". Keep in mind that this is an experimental featrure. You might want to consider using a displace modifier instead, it is more controllable.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45873/blender-cycles-true-displacement and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34902/how-can-i-adjust-cycles-material-displacement-amount/34903#34903